# VBA: Application.PrintOut

Tags: vba, printing, ms-word

i am using this code to PrintOut a document three times in vba:

```
...     
 Application.PrintOut fileName:="", Range:=wdPrintAllDocument, Item:= _
        wdPrintDocumentContent, Copies:=1, Pages:="", PageType:=wdPrintAllPages, _
        ManualDuplexPrint:=False, Collate:=True, Background:=True, PrintToFile:= _
        False, PrintZoomColumn:=0, PrintZoomRow:=0, PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, _
        PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0
...
```

sometimes if i run this line of code, it will stopp working. Word freeze and nothing happend. I can only stop the process. i checked the PrinterSettings by

```
MsgBox Application.ActivePrinter
```

The activeprinter exists and is ready. What else can be the problem?
I am using word 2007.

Thanks for hints

Comment: What is the error that you get `*sometimes*`?

Comment: there is no error i can see: word freezes i can only kill the process. Thats my problem. Maybe there is an advanced logging possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Document.PrintOut because Application.PrintOut prints **active document**, so if you're simultaneously working with another word document you can send to printer your document instead of desired one.